# ubuntu 16.04 LTS Login Loop & Black screen TTY

Tags: 16.04, graphics, login, lts, tty

First of all, don't judge me instantly, this might seem like duplicated question but honestly, I can't find solution to my case. That's why I came here.

Okey here's the deal. I started my morning by starting my computer and log in to Ubuntu. Everything worked like a charm! Then, just like time to time, system updater popped up and there were couple updates. I checked them, and everything looked great and then I clicked "install" or "update" - for some reason not sure what that button says, but anyway... Then, meanwhile I was finishing my coffee, the updates finished and I decided to start my workday.
At the moment I'm working on with big video project so I opened kdenlive. But unexpectedly it doesn't opened at all, and kdenlive wasn't only one whom behavior was weird. So I was still bit sleepy so I haven't enough energy to start figuring out what's going on so I decided restart computer and crossed my fingers that it would be magic reboot. Well.. it wasn't.

Login loop decided to stopped by. First reaction was, oh sh*t is my system broken? Did I lost everything?

I guess I didn't. I assuming I could fix this if I'd be able to open TTY.
`ctrl` + `alt` + `f1` give me black screen.
I followd this answer: [Graphics issues after/while installing Ubuntu 16.04/16.10 with NVIDIA graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-while-installing-ubuntu-16-04-with-nvidia-graphics/760935#760935)

and I edit my GRUB and I placed `nouveau.modeset=0` in there and reboot my system but no luck.

After couple of hours I figured that TTY is the only way how I can get this working again, right?
Do you have any suggestion how could I open my TTY and get rid of the login loop?
I really appreciate every reply.

Thank you!

**EDIT**
When I place `nouveau.modeset=0` in GRUB and reboot, this come: `/dev/sda8:clean, 412123/3055616 files, 2982833/12207104 blocks`

when this is on the screen, I'm unable to type anything and after couple seconds the normal login screen appear and I'm still unable to open TTY.

-Cecily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl + Alt + F2</kbd> to get to a terminal. Login then shut down the graphic interface:

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

Then update:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then get rid of all nvidia stuff:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*
```

then try:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-340
```

Then

```
sudo reboot
```

Hope that helps! This is just a from-memory suggestion on similar issues I've had.

Comment: I'd be more than glad to do that, but the problem is that I can't get to the terminal.

Comment: I meant a TTY terminal. Try ctrl-alt-f1 or ctrl-alt-f2 (etc) until you get one.  Might have to hold down for a bit. What happens when you try?

Comment: ctr-alt-f1-6 each one shows only black screen.

Comment: Try holding down shift when rebooting to get to the grub menu. Use "e" (as I recall) to be able to do temporary editing of what grub will use. Remove "splash quiet"  and add "3" at the end of that line to tell the system to boot into run-level 3 which is just console/text mode. And maybe also change whatever it says after gfxmode to "text" (no ") so it doesn't try to change grapichs mode in th emiddle of the boot.  And then ctrl-x or whatever it says at the bottom of the screen for instructions to boot. Ideally it will show the boot progress and hand-off to a tty login.

Comment: if I remove "quiet splash" and add "3" my ubuntu machine doesn't reboot. What if I'd use instead `nouveau.modeset=0` and `gfxmode text` this would be pretty much same thing, right? Btw, how about $vt_handoff? Should I remove that too? End of the Linux line in GRUB look like this: `ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff` by default

Comment: quiet will hide all the text/console messages generated by the boot sequence. splash will (try) to display a pretty screen (the purple with Ubuntu logo). nouveau.modeset tells the nouveau module what modeset, but only makes a difference if the nouveau is being used which it's probably not because you had nvidia. The vt_handoff is which tty to automatically switch to. Try gettiing rid of all that stuff, so nothing after "ro". Also try removing the gfxmode line and load_video line.  Also try with a 3 after ro (space between).

Comment: Now I finally see TTY. Before I follow your answer, I wanna make sure one thing. Is there any chance that my machine would crash so bad that I wouldn't be able to get my data out of my ubuntu machine? This is completely grey area to me, so this might be silly question.

Comment: No, this stuff is just removing the video drivers and thus any ability to show a GUI until a working video driver is installed. None of your data will be involved. As a worst-case scenario of never being able to get a working GUI (unlikely) you could always copy your files out over the network from tty or physically remove the disk and mount on another computer to copy the files.

Comment: It worked! Thank you for your help! You're amazing! Your replies were so perfect, not just a answer, you also told me how this works and what will happen etc. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to be of service! You kind thanks made my day :-)